# Im stuck at error cannot find module in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I used the discord.js guide for Economy System and i get this error:

```
  Error: Cannot find module './models/UserItems.js'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/Banky/dbObjects.js
- /home/runner/Banky/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Banky/dbObjects.js:12:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
```

Can anybody help me how to fix it?

This is my path:

[image]

Comment: Could we see your file structure? Its difficult to troubleshoot without it.

Comment: I added the path on the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring `UserItems.js` not `UsersItems.js`.

```js
... = require('./models/UserItems.js');  ❌
... = require('./models/UsersItems.js'); ✅
```

Comment: And in node_modules, what should i have?

Comment: Sometimes all you need is a second pair of eyes!